God and Law of Identity Paradox
Heard of this one somewhere and I'm wondering if there's an explanation or not. This is directed to theists who believe God created logic.

God created logic, so he is unbounded by the rules of logic
The law of identity is a rule of logic (from what I understand, the law of identity just says x is x)
God exists outside out of the law of identity
Therefore, God is not God

I'm not too familiar with philosophy, so is this just some semantic wordplay that doesn't really mean anything or what?

If God is not bound by logic then there is no point to making logical arguments about him, including this one, or paying attention to their conclusions. Reliance on faith alone rather than reason when it comes to God is called fideism.

What happens if you replace God with universe  in the first and third premises?

Logic not a thing that actually physically exists, so it cannot be "created". It's a thing humans made up to describe how reality works. If a theist wants to get more specific and say e.g. contradictory things can be true about God at the same time, that's nonsensical and that would be throwing away one's ability to say pretty much anything about God, including whether he exists, so good luck being a theist from there (although theists typically say such things as a band-aid solution to theological problems, with little interest in the far-reaching implications of what they're saying).

The argument falls down at 1. It is a non sequitur. And at 3. If God exists outside out of the law of identity, how can you draw the conclusion of 4, which is about identity? But of course God is not God – nobody knows what God is, apart from representing things we don't know.

@NotThatGuy Logic is just made up? Is there any logic to your comment or did you just make up your comment? Did god create logic or did the universe?. if rhe universe began, was the origin of logic simultaneous to the origin of the universe? If they were both simultaneously, how could the universe have been the cause of logic?

Existing outside the Law of Identity does not mean that God does not "obey" the Law of Identity. It means that God is not restricted by the Law of Identity.

While you can goad many lay theists to say almost anything that sounds vaguely worshipful about God with suitable prompting, almost all scholarly theists would reject the premise. And since an important part of belief is which experts you are willing to defer to about things you'd otherwise have to guess about, there's a strong argument that even the most prompt-able lay theist doesn't actually believe it.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipotence_paradox for a brief introduction to the various takes God and logic, albeit one unfortunately light on references to Islamic theologians.

It's not purely a semantic wordplay.
God, being outside the laws of logic, is indescribable. It is true that the law of identity is also a law of logic. To then go from this to saying God is not God is not a permissable step since you're applying logic and we've already asserted that logic cannot be applied to God.

The statement "logic cannot be applied to God" is a logical statement about God, so you couldn't even say that. You couldn't even reason about whether logic applies to God or not. Also, the statement "God is indescribable" is self contradictory since you're describing God as indescribable.

@CJDennis: You're playing semantic games. To describe something as indescribable is not to describe it at all - there is no definite description here.

There's a difference between "is not described" and "cannot be described". I understand "indescribable" to be the latter. If you say "nothing can be known about God", that's something that's known about God. If you say "nothing is known about God", that could be.

This series of rules depends on a very particular set of rules of inference which are not usually accepted.  In particular, it is unusual to state that because an entity is unbound by something it is bound to refute it, and you depend on that to reach your conclusion (4).
Consider a comparable line of logic regarding numbers:

Real numbers are unbounded by the laws of integers
Integers are odd or even.
2.0 is a real number
Thus 2.0 is unbounded by the concepts of odd or even
Thus 2.0 is not odd nor even.

Or an abstract algebra equivalent:

Monoids are unbounded by the laws of groups.
Group operators obey the associative property
Thus monoid operators do not have the associative property

(For those not familiar with abstract algebra, monoid operators are absolutely associative.  Its part of the definition of a monoid)
A more common reading (at least in my opinion) would be to say that since God is unbounded by logic, God may be God or God may not be God.  Any statement regarding the identity of God must be asserted above and beyond the rules of logic and the given axioms. Or if you want to go even further, it is entirely plausible that neither statement is true (as one can also consider the law of the excluded middle in such arguments)

Just for fun, an alternate argument using your first two statements:

God created logic, so he is unbounded by the rules of logic
The law of identity is a rule of logic (from what I understand, the law of identity just says x is x)
Therefore, God is "unbounded" by the Law of Indentity

So God is not restricted to be God. God can be anyone or anything. According to my definition of "unbounded".

Frame Challenge

God created logic, ...

Philosophers created logic. Greek philosophers noticed certain regularities in the way the people used language to reason, and they abstracted a theory, which they called "logic".
